# classifying a dataset in java

Tags: java, instance, classification

Hi I am trying to implement my own classifier in a java .Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
 import weka.core.*;


public class RandomProbability extends Classifier {
    Instances data;

    public RandomProbability ()
    {
        /*DataSource d = new DataSource("C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-6\\data\\labor.arff");
        data=((Object) d).getSourceData();*/
        DataSource source = null;
        try {
            source = new DataSource("C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-6\\data\\labor.arff");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

         try {
            Instances instances = source.getDataSet();

             //instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);

             // Print header and instances.
             System.out.println("\nDataset:\n");
             System.out.println(instances);
```

Now the problem is I cant get it to classify the data in the dataset (as good or bad).
I need help in trying to access a single instance in this code.

Comment: Isn't that kind of validation saying good or bad? Or you are looking for checking some instance etc. Please clarify in the question.

Comment: Not validation.Basically my labor data set has these two classes( good or bad) for the data and I have to implement my own classifier  but I am clueless on how to read the class of the data in the dataset(.arff file).

Comment: You could use object instanceOf MyClass to classify type of instance?

Comment: Im a beginner so can you please elaborate how to code that

Answer (score 0):

You could use instanceOf operator as below:

```
int countA = 0, countB=0; 
double pred; 
for (int i=0;i<57;i++) { 
    pred = classifyInstance(instances.instance(i)); 
    System.out.println("===== Classified instance ====="); 
    System.out.println("Class predicted:" + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred)); 
    if (instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred).toString().equals("bad")) { 
         countB++; 
    } else { 
         countA++; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is instanceof here?

Comment: int countA = 0, countB=0;
    double pred;
    for (int i=0;i<57;i++)
    {
        pred = classifyInstance(instances.instance(i));
              System.out.println("===== Classified instance =====");
              System.out.println("Class predicted:" + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
              if (instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred).toString()=="bad")
              {
               countB++;
              }
              else {
               countA++;
              } 
    
    }

Comment: I tried something like this but it only classifies every instanvce as bad i dont know why although incrementing i should take care of that                                                          int countA = 0, countB=0;double pred;
    for (int i=0;i<57;i++)
{pred=classifyInstance(instances.instance(System.out.println("===== Classified instance =====");
System.out.println("Class predicted:" + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));                 if (instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred).toString()==" {
               countB++;}
              else {countA++;} }

Comment: Paste input and output that you are expecting.

Comment: almas can you please see into it that why is it classifying every instance as bad. It is not so in my data set. Its so frustrating

Comment: 2,4.5,4,?,?,40,?,?,2,no,10,below_average,no,half,?,half,bad
2,4.5,4,?,none,40,?,?,5,?,11,average,?,full,yes,full,good

Comment: my data set is like the one iv pasted above

Comment: and output as well please. i.e. print statements

Comment: if you mean that I am expecting then

Comment: The ouput im getting is good instances0 bad instances57               but i want it to be right like good instances 25 and bad instances 32  but is it currently classifying everything as bad . why is that?

Comment: System.out.println("good instances"+countA);
System.out.println("bad instances"+ countB);

Comment: when you run your code as per above, you should see on console something like Class predicted:blah blah.. what you get can you paste here. I hope am very clear?

Comment: My console output (some lines)      Class predicted:bad
===== Classified instance =====
Class predicted:bad
===== Classified instance =====
Class predicted:bad
===== Classified instance =====
Class predicted:bad
good instances0
bad instances57

Comment: So there are issues with another part of code. Paste your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```
package dm;
//import javax.activation.DataSource;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.classifiers.*;
import weka.core.*;
import org.jfree.data.*;

import weka.core.*;
public class RandomProbability extends Classifier {
    Instances data;

    public RandomProbability ()
    {
        /*DataSource d = new DataSource("C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-6\\data\\labor.arff");
        data=((Object) d).getSourceData();*/
        DataSource source = null;
        try {
            source = new DataSource("C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-6\\data\\labor.arff");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
            Instances instances = source.getDataSet();

             instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);

             // Print header and instances.
             System.out.println("\nDataset:\n");
             System.out.println(instances);

             int total=instances.numInstances();
             System.out.println("total"+total);

             Attribute attr= instances.attribute(16);
             System.out.println("attr"+attr);

             // checking class
             int countA = 0, countB=0;
             double pred;
             for (int i=0;i<57;i++)
             {
                    pred=0;
                    pred = classifyInstance(instances.instance(i));
                    System.out.println("===== Classified instance =====");
                    System.out.println("Class predicted:" + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
                    if (instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred).toString().equals("bad"))
                    {
                        countB++;
                    }
                    else {
                        countA++;
                    } 

             }
             System.out.println("good instances"+countA);
             System.out.println("bad instances"+ countB);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void buildClassifier (Instances data)
    {

    }

    public double classifyInstance (Instance inst)
    {
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: classifier class? instances class, attribute class?